# c++ templated class with functionpointer to variadic function

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I want to implement a spooler/worker class in c++ that has a function to push new tasks into the class to have them executed by a background thread. The task gets appended to a queue and if the worker isn't running it is started.

For better reuse i want to use a variadic template arguments for variadic tasks, but i have trouble formulating the template header.

```
template <void (*TFunction)(typename ... TParams)> //a parameter pack is not allowed here
class worker
{
public:
    push(TParams... args);
};
```

```
template <typename ... TParams, void (*TFunction)(TParams...)> //template parameter pack not at end of parameter list
class worker
{
public:
    push(TParams... args);
};
```

I have two ideas that would work, but i don't like either.

```
template <typename ... TParams>
class worker
{
public:
    worker(void(*function)(TParams...)): function_(function) { }
    push(TParams... args);

private:
    const void (*function_)(TParams...);
};
```

```
template <typename ... TParams>
struct variadic
{
    template <void*(TFunction)(TParams...)>
    class worker {
    public:
        push(TParams... args);
    };
};
```

Is there a way to accept a function with variadic parameters with a single template header?

Thank you, everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With specialization:

```
template <auto value>
class worker;

template <typename ... TParams, void (*F)(TParams...)>
class worker<F>
{
public:
    void push(TParams... args);
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b811c42ea2e29cf)

Comment: Thanks for the demo, i had some problems getting it to work, but it's all good now.
The first one does exactly what i want.